# Iterate over vector using loop c++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, vector

Let's say I have a vector of long long elements:

```
std::vector<long long>V {1, 2, 3};
```

I have seen that in order to iterate over the vector you can do this:

```
for (auto i = v.begin() ; i != v.end() ; i++)
   cout<<*i;
```

`i++` means `i` grows by `1`, but shouldn't the address go up 8 bytes to print the next element? So "growing" part of the for loop(for any type) should look like this:

```
i += sizeof(v[0]);
```

I'm assuming an address can hold 1 byte , so if the starting address of an integer would be 1000 , then its total allocation will be represented by adresses:1000 , 1001 , 1002 , 1003.I would like to understand memory better so I'd be thankful if you could help me.

Comment: Even easier: `for (auto&& value : V)`.

Comment: You have roughtly `int* pi = /*..*/; char* pc = reintepret_cast<char*>(pi); assert(pc + sizeof(int) == reintepret_cast<char*>(pi + 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you increment a pointer it goes up by the "size of" the pointer's type. Remember, for a given pointer `i`, `i[0]` is the first element and is equivalent to `*(i + 1)`.

Iterators tend to work in a very similar fashion so their operation is familiar, they *feel* like pointers due to how `operator*` and `operator->` are implemented.

In other words, the meaning of `i++` depends *entirely* on what `i` is and what `operator++` will do on that type. Seeing `++` does not automatically mean `+1`. For iterators it has a very specific meaning, and that depends entirely on the type.

For `std::vector` it moves a pointer up to the next entry. For other structures it might navigate a linked list. You could write your own class where it makes a database call, reads a file from disk, or basically whatever you want.

Now if you do `i += sizeof(v[0])` instead then you're moving up an arbitrary number of places in your array. It depends on what the size of that entry is, which depends a lot on your [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture).

`std::vector` is really simple, it's just a straight up block of memory treated like an array. You can even get a pointer to this via the [`data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) function.

In other words think of `i++` as "move up one index" not "move up one byte".

Answer (score 1):

One of the nice things about the way you've written this code is that you don't need to worry about bytes.

Your `auto` type for `i` is masking the fact that it's a vector iterator, in other words, a special type that is designed for accessing members of a vector of `long long`. This means that `*i` evaluates to a `long long` pulled from whichever member of the vector `i` is currently indexing, so `i++` advances `i` to index the next member of the vector.

Now, in terms of low level implementation, the values `1, 2, 3` are probably sitting in adjacent 8-byte blocks of memory, and `i` is probably implemented as a pointer, and incrementing `i` is probably implemented by adding 8 to its value, but each of those assumptions is going to depend on your architecture and the implementation of your compiler. And as I said, it's something you probably don't need to worry about.

Comment: "the values 1, 2, 3 are probably sitting in adjacent 8-byte blocks of memory"  Nope - it's a long long.  C++11 requires this to be at least 64 bit.  You can be sure however, that the memory they do take up is contiguous, as that's one of the requirements of std::vector

Comment: Thank you!!One more question:does one adress point to one single byte?

Comment: @UKMonkey so how would you have worded it? Sitting in blocks of memory that are definitely adjacent and at least 8 bytes each but on today's computers probably no more than that? I was trying for a simple explanation.

Comment: @asddsdsadsa I'm not sure if answering that question is going to clarify anything. The pointer stores an address, and yes that's technically the location of a single byte, _i.e._ the first byte used to store the `long long` you're interested in. At least, on systems that allow each byte to be addressed. From the perspective of a "pointer to `long long`", however, the memory is divided into (probably) 8-byte chunks and it is pointing at one of those.